# &nbsp; displays a tiny line

Tags: html, css, html-entities

when I make `&nbsp;` in my site, it displays a tiny line, which can be hidden on some elements because I'm usually using them on CSS buttons, but I have an if statement that says if this show the result if not show a non breaking space.

How do you reset the `&nbsp;` to display nothing?

Comment: Are you talking about the underline decoration below a link?  Or are these nbsp's NOT links?

Comment: If you're using `&nbsp;` as dummy content and then hiding the real content as a picture of text as a background image, then you're doing it wrong. It sounds like that is the root cause of your problem, so you should address that rather then building another hack on top of you existing hack.

Comment: Some are links, some are not, also should I just leave the space blanks instead of using a `&nbsp;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this **tiny line** an outline? Try this in css:

```
outline:none;
```

Is this **tiny line** an underline? Try this in css:

```
text-decoration:none;
```

Is that something else, elaborate your question.

Answer (score 2):

The "tiny line" is most likely an underline/border. Remove `text-decoration` and/or borders.

Why are you using `&nbsp;`s if you don't want them to do anything, though? No need to clutter the source with them unless you really need them.

Comment: Thanks, I shall try that, I'm using them for things like CSS buttons, to force them to display, I've learned it's a good idea to put something in between the opening and closing tags to make sure they display. `<button type="submit" class="submit" nsme="OFFLINE2" id="fullfor_btn" title="Fullfør bestillingen nå" value="">&nbsp;</button>`